# How to use an if condition in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I want select the `matches` with the `MAX` gameweek if the status of all `matches` is setted to `3`, or the `matches` with `MIN` gameweek how can I do this?

*Data sample*

```
id | status | gameweek | round_id 
 1     3         3          1
 2     3         3          1
 3     1         3          1
 4     1         4          1
 5     1         4          1
 6     1         4          1
```

the final result should be: `1, 2, 3` because not all the match has played.
I was able to setup a query for `MAX`:

```
SELECT MAX(gameweek) FROM `match` m WHERE round_id = 1 AND m.status = 3
```

but I have some difficult to implement an IF condition, someone could help me?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In the solution proposed by the users I noticed that I doesn't explain well a particular situation: if all the matches of a round doesn't have the status 3, the query should return the MIN(gameweek) of the round_id specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, simpler than I imagined, I discovered that I can achieve this target using the `COALESCE` operator, so:

```
m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(
                    CASE WHEN m2.status < 3 
                         THEN m2.gameweek END), 
                   MAX(m2.gameweek))
                   FROM `match` m2 
                   WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right, you could use a `CASE`. If a record with a `status` other than `3` exists return the minumum `gameweek`, else the maximum. Compare the result to the `gameweek`.

```
SELECT `m1`.*
       FROM `match` `m1`
       WHERE `m1`.`round_id` = 1
             AND `m1`.`gameweek` = CASE
                                     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                         FROM `match` `m2`
                                                         WHERE `m2`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`
                                                               AND `m2`.`status` <> 3) THEN
                                       (SELECT min(`m3`.`gameweek`)
                                               FROM `match` `m3`
                                               WHERE `m3`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`)
                                     ELSE
                                       (SELECT max(`m4`.`gameweek`)
                                               FROM `match` `m4`
                                               WHERE `m4`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`)
                                   END;
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to limit it to a certain `round_id`. It's in your query but not in the text. If you don't want it, remove all the conditions related to `round_id`.

---

Edit:

To use the maximum `gameweek` if not all `status` of a round are equal to 3 and the minimum `gameweek` otherwise you can check if the minimum of the `status` equals the maximum (i.e. all status are the same) and if it is equal to 3.

```
SELECT `m1`.*
       FROM `match` `m1`
       WHERE `m1`.`round_id` = 1
             AND `m1`.`gameweek` = CASE
                                     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT min(`m2`.`status`)
                                                         FROM `match` `m2`
                                                         WHERE `m2`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`
                                                         HAVING min(`m2`.`status`) <> max(`m2`.`status`)
                                                                OR min(`m2`.`status`) <> 3) THEN
                                       (SELECT min(`m3`.`gameweek`)
                                               FROM `match` `m3`
                                               WHERE `m3`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`)
                                     ELSE
                                       (SELECT max(`m4`.`gameweek`)
                                               FROM `match` `m4`
                                               WHERE `m4`.`round_id` = `m1`.`round_id`)
                                   END;
```

Comment: @Charanoglu: I have, it worked for me as I understood your question. But as you didn't provide DDL nor DML my setup might have been different. Consider to provide DDL and DML in the question along with more sample data and desired results, maybe for both (or all) cases.

Comment: I get: `4 errors were found during the analysis.

Keyword not recognized. (near "CASE" in position 99)
Keyword not recognized. (near "WHEN" in position 119)
Keyword not recognized. (near "EXISTS" in position 124)
Unexpected token. (near "(" to position 131)`

Comment: @Charanoglu: Have you changed or embedded it somewhere? The syntax is OK as it stands (alone).

Comment: I just pasted your query in phpmyadmin and changed the round_id to my own like 1293 instead of 1, I didn't change the syntax

Comment: @Charanoglu maybe you dont have round_id 1293 in your database then.. Besides i would not advice to use this query on larger table because of the co-related subqueries which tends to optimize very very badly on MySQL.

Comment: I have matches with round_id = 1293, all these matches have as status 1, so the query should return the MIN(gameweek), with the query of Radim I get an empty result, but instead working if almost a match have as status 5

Comment: @Charanoglu: I suspect there is some leftovers of another query somewhere, maybe not "visible" due to white spaces/empty lines etc..

Comment: @Charanoglu: As I already wrote: Elaborate your question. Otherwise this is likely to become an endless chain of comments with no result after all.

Comment: @Charanoglu: Still not easy to understand. But I gave it another try. See my edit.

Comment: @stickybit could you please add a fiddle? I also get the  error above

Comment: @Charanoglu: Sorry, I tried my best to help you, but I'll stop here! Remember, it is you who asked the question, thus it is you who have to provide all possible means to explain the question and a test environment if needed. If anybody should provide a fiddle, it is you, certainly not me. And you should have done that in the first place (or simply just provide DDL and DML in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can be more than one `round_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `match` m 
WHERE (gameweek, round_id ) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(gameweek),round_id 
  FROM `match` m 
  WHERE round_id = 1 AND m.status = 3
  GROUP BY round_id
)
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77c3aee460595c4726e4566a0b089748)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your query but return an empty result, have you tried?

Comment: @Charanoglu I have added the demo

Comment: Wait i overlooked `the status = 3` i really really need some coffee iam going to redeem mine last comment... "since the subquery returns the pair (3,1). "  No the subquery will return only one record  record because there isn't a `GROUP BY` and this query will fail on sql mode with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled because you are mixing non-aggregated column with a aggregated column without `GROUP BY` which is infact invalid SQL see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d814d9/9 @Charanoglu make sure you add a `GROUP BY` in the subquery

Comment: @RadimBača Ok this seems to work if there are match with status = 3 but if there is no match with that status nothing will be returned, instead the query should return the MIN(gameweek)

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right, that without `GROUP BY` are the results little bit random ... i have added it there. I probably need a cofee as well :)

Comment: Besides trusting on the automatic sort with `GROUP BY` without using `ORDER BY` was deprecated from i believe from MySQL 5.6 or 5.7.. MySQL 8.0 is the first version that works like this. MYSQL 8.0 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ps8mWYp5jJBKmd8bg3Tqq/1  vs MySQL 5.7 see the difference in the results. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ps8mWYp5jJBKmd8bg3Tqq/0 .. Thats why i also added `ORDER BY` in mine demo ... Or if you don't need to sort or don't care about the order use `ORDER BY NULL` to disable the sort completly should also give the qeury a performance boost in MySQL versions under MySQL 8.0

Comment: @RadimBača How about the min gameweek? Your query works only for match that have as status 5, all other status should return MIN(gameweek) but your query return an empty result